# Detect scroll end in React Native ScrollView, snap to page

Tags: react-native

React Native [ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html) has a prop [pagingEnabled](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#pagingenabled) . However, it assumes that the width of each page (or child component) in the ScrollView is equal to the width of the ScrollView.

How can we mend this to make it work correctly for pages that are smaller than the ScrollView?

**Is it possible to detect when the user stops scrolling?** Then we can easily write our own code to snap to the right page.

Edit: There are a few other ways to mend this by using props that are only available on iOS, so this is particularly a problem on Android.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There are two different props you can set to React Native [ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html) which takes a callback to notify that scroll has ended. (They are now both documented.)

---

[**onScrollEndDrag** function](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#onscrollenddrag)

Called as soon as the user lets go of the ScrollView (lifts the finger from the screen).

<s>Working sample: https://rnplay.org/apps/Ufv6Cg</s> (No longer available)

---

[**onMomentumScrollEnd** function](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#onmomentumscrollend)

Called when the ScrollView stops sliding (it will normally continue to slide a little bit after the user has lifted the finger from the screen).

<s>Working sample: https://rnplay.org/apps/BPgG_g</s> (No longer available)

---

*Note:* I could not find the methods in the API documentation for any React Native component, but they work as shown in the examples. I saw  them used [here](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/blob/a5ce8d422a53abe7d968827afee7b758f453f723/index.js#L463) in [react-native-snap-carousel](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel).

Comment: also wanted to add `onScrollBeginDrag` is another one that triggers at the start of a drag https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/62b20ce582383dd36c07b5d541cde6a7d13cabc6/React/Views/RCTScrollView.h#L54

Comment: oddly enough onScrollEndDrag is not listed anymore on react native API, but still works.

Comment: Both your sample links are broken, and they ain't in the Wayback Machine either.

Comment: `onMomentumScrollEnd` is now documented; I've opened PRs to document `onScrollEndDrag` and `onScrollBeginDrag` at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/17368 and https://github.com/facebook/react-native-website/pull/99.

Comment: Nice! I'll update my answer when the new version of the documentation is released ([here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html)).

Comment: broken links bro

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use the [snapToOffsets](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#snaptooffsets) property which does exactly what you want.

> This can be used for paginating through variously sized children that have lengths smaller than the scroll view.

Answer (score 2):

I did it like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {ScrollView} from 'react-native';
    
function handleInfinityScroll(event) {
   let mHeight = event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.height;
   let cSize = event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height;
   let Y = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
   if (Math.ceil(mHeight + Y) >= cSize) return true;
   return false;
}
    
const HomeScreen= ({navigation}) => (
  <ScrollView
    onScroll={({event}) => {
      if (handleInfinityScroll(event)) {
        console.log("END");
      }
    }}
  >
    <></>
  </ScrollView>
);
    
export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can play the video which is on display and pause all other videos?

Comment: @BilalYaqoob Using react-native-video you can use a state for stop the video after the component has loaded.
https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/issues/494#issuecomment-281853423

Comment: Yes I know this and I am doing this, But I have a list in flatlist and if I pause all pause and if I run all run, my app is like TikTok feed, I want to detect which is on display so I can play that and pause all others. And when I scroll to the second video I play that video and pause the previous video and also all the other videos.

Comment: @BilalYaqoob I got it, u should use refs.
 videoref.current.setNativeProps({ paused: false })
https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/issues/2458

Comment: Thank you very much for this link, I was finding a solution like that from 3 weeks. I will try applying this solution.

Answer (score 0):

As an option, You can use `debounce` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce).
And don't forget to `clear()` it.

```
import { debounce } from 'debounce';

...

const listenerDebounce = debounce((_) => {
    // Scroll Did End
  }, 160);

return <FlatList
  {...yourProps}
  onScroll={Animated.event(
    [{
        nativeEvent: {
            contentOffset: { y: scrollOffsetValue }
        }
    }],
    {
        useNativeDriver: true,
        listener: listenerDebounce
    },
)
/>;

...
```

Comment: Question was for ScrollView not for FlatList component.

Comment: @PinkiDhakad FlatList contains all of the props from ScrollView. Including it's onScroll method